# Error: Invalid Conversion From 'Int' to 'Int*' When Initializing GLUT

Tags: c, opengl, glut

Here's the problem: when compiling, it gives an error "**invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]**" on the line 3 of this example code.

Originally, I didn't have the code as I do now, what I had it as caused errors, and gave me a recommendation, "**try ____**", which got me to where I am now. I've searched for the error it gave me (invalid conversion from...) and none of the pages I'd seen had actually had a fix for the example I have, so I look up my error with extra search terms like "**opengl**" and "**glut**", which gave one result that had a fix, the only problem is, the compiler still gave an error.

Here is an example of the code, shortened down to show only what is causing the problem

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>
main(){
    glutInit(_argc,_argv);
}
```

Comment: `main(int argc, char **argv){ glutInit(&argc, argv); }`

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all: you provide an `int` (integer) where `int*` (pointer to integer) is expected. In this case -- that you minimized well -- it is the first parameter to `glutInit()`.

This function handles some of the arguments and wants to change their number in the course. Therefore you must hand over its pointer:

```
glutInit(&_argc,_argv);
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but when I do that and compile the program it gives three errors, `undefined reference to '__glutInitWithExit@12'`, `undifined reference to '__glutCreatWindowWithExit@8'`, and `undifined reference to '__glutCreatMenuWithExit@8'`

Comment: [About undefined reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Well, qrani, this is another question which can be answered for example by reading the case @Ripi2 pointed to. Kudos to him! You will also get a lot of help if you ask your favorite search engine about "how to link with glut".